# Is there a way to get a pointer to the underlying value of std::atomic?

Tags: c++, stdatomic

```
int *ptr;
std::atomic<int> s;

ptr = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&s);
```

`ptr` comes from C part of the code, while `s` comes from the C++ part.

This code is not correct, but is there anything similar possible? So that when `s` is updated, I can access the updated value with `ptr`.

Comment: Requirement is unclear. What is your use case?

Comment: Have you looked at whether [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) could be used here to replace `std::atomic`  ?

Comment: getting a point to the stored value defeats the purpose of an `std::atomic` because it bypassed all that `std::atomic` has to offer

Comment: Do you mean you need to pass an `int*` to "C" code? But you have an atomic in C++?
If so protect your pointer by a mutex and also acquire that same mutex when making the call to the "C" code. (You don't want to change the pointer when the "C" code is busy with it)

Comment: I think you are better off using a `_Atomic` in "C" as well if possbile, also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868704/how-to-properly-mix-stdatomic-between-c-and-c

Answer (score 2):

No. A `std::atomic<int>` is not an `int`, and it isn't required to contain one. Even in the likely case that the object representations of them are the same, it is a strict aliasing violation to `reinterpret_cast` like that. You can't form a dereferencable pointer to an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no, `atomic<int>` is a type that admits the same values as `int`, and (some of) the same operators, but it is a distinct type with distinct semantics.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, I'm just saying that the standard does not require there to be a data member of the corresponding type. Yes of course the implementation is most likely with the same object representation

Answer (score 2):

There's no well-defined way to do that; `std::atomic<int>` is opaque.  This is why C++20 introduced [`std::atomic_ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) instead to make it possible for programs with a single-threaded phase to only do atomic accesses when needed.

If your C function will definitely be the only thread accessing the object while it's running, use plain `int s;` and have your concurrent C++ accesses use `std::atomic_ref` in other parts of your program.

Otherwise, you need accesses from C to be thread-safe, too.  `std::atomic_int` (`std::atomic<int>` should be ABI-compatible with C `atomic_int` (`_Atomic int`).

C++23 makes C11-style `stdatomic.h` available for enhanced compatibility, like `_Atomic int *ptr`.  Without that, it should still be safe to pass pointers but you might need to go through `void*`.

(It's up to the implementation to make C and C++ atomics ABI-compatible, but IIRC the standard recommends that they should be, and it's a design goal for real-world compilers that implement them.)