# Does getOpaque/order_relaxed/read_once have influence on the processor, or just the compiler during memory hoisting?

Tags: java, c++, compiler-optimization, processor, memory-barriers

I've had some discussion with multiple people on this issue, and there are some points that makes the usage of memory ordering fences on load situations somewhat confusing.

The first bullet point seems to be:

- a) The level of processor reordering is limited by the amount of
  method de-virtualization done by the compiler.

  - a.1) The processor can reorder instructions WITHIN a virtual method,
    BUT NOT OUT of the virtual method (unless de-virtualized).
  - a.2) The processor CAN reorder virtual method calls, between OTHER virtual
    method calls... AS LONG as these methods DO NOT depend on each other
    (no reference interdependence).
- b) Optimizations such as parallelization ARE DONE on specific
  mathematical operations done on ALU, and NEVER performed on
  programmer's "macro" logic code... even if it could.
- c) The processor would NEVER do something outlandish like "memory
  hoisting", these events are ALWAYS a compiler side responsibility.
  (see "d")
- d) Register promotion (prosessor's bare-bones "memory hoisting"
  mechanic) can only occur on primitives and require explicit instructions.

  - d.1) My assumption is that libraries such as Java's Math. would
    make use of such optimizations, but outside this, compilers will
    never make a processor promote a register UNLESS NO OTHER register is
    involved in the concurrent mathematical operation.

On Java's compiler...

- e) Java's compiler and (JIT) implementations NEVER parallelize COMPLEX interdependencies, even if they could.

  - e.1) Only on simple loops where no interdependencies are required.... like Arrays library Array/Collection pure-functional construction.
- f) Activities such as memory hoisting are done on this level, NOT on the processor level.

  - - Explanation of f: just think about it, If there is NO specific instruction to promote or prevent register promotion on memories other than primitives on the **processor level**, then latency prevention can only be achieved in the compiler level via hoisting... WHILE actions like double-checking DO INVOLVE the processor since the processor has the means to reorder and simplify the code... damaging the double-check in the process.

Now let's examine the argument:

> "Ok, it works now, but... what about weakly memory ordered processors?"

It seems to me that `volatile` AND `getAcquire` loads are "levers" meant to handle COMPILER + processor reordering BEHAVIOR... volatile(`seq_const`) and acquire DO HAVE influence over previous and subsequent loads and stores....

BUT `getOpaque`/`memory_ordered_relaxed` is JUST a compiler handle.... that does NOTHING on the processor level... depending on the case, either it be hoisting-prevention... or simplification-prevention.

Since ALL it prevents is hoisting, then processors have no idea a `getOpaque` was even used...(?), depending on the case.

The biggest clue about my assumption is the name the lynux kernel defines the fence... as `read_once()`, as to tell the compiler "This will not be read more than once, please do NOT HOIST-optimize"

---

So, de-virtualization is a behavior that "almost never happens" according to some answers on this site, and even if it DOES, it will only occur on situations on which the scope is "contextually aknowledged"... aka private/protected methods (inheritance by extension...)

This exempts:
public methods (relative to an outer scope), lambdas and static methods(not so sure about this one tbh).

In the next code I will try to demonstrate how a specific syntax will prevent load hoisting, by taking advantage of method virtualization.
Note: On double-checking getOpaque/relaxed is still required.

IF... for the code:

```
   int plain = 0;
   final Executor executor;

   Runnable readRunnable = () -> {
      T localPlain = this.plain; //One important factor of the why this will always work
                                 // properly is HOW the load is the first thing 
                                 // to happen in the stack.
                                 // Even if the load is done within the 'while' of a CAS.
                                 // The load is never hoisted, but...
                                 // "Ok, it works now, but... what about weakly memory ordered processors?"
      print(localPlain);
   };

   long delay = 20; //Millis
   MyExecutor exec = new MyExecutor(executor, delay, readRunnable); //This one's built in the constructor, please pardon my laziness...

   public void read() {
      exec.execute(); // will execute the inner final runnable.
   }
    
   public static void main() {
      Executor ex = Executors...
      PlainClass pc = new PlainClass(ex);
      print(pc.plain); // will read 0;
      pc.read(); // will read 3;
      pc.setPlain(3);
   }
    
   public void setPlain(int value) {
      this.plain = value;
   }
```

The source of the pc.plain read... even if coming from the same register, the compiler will be unable to hoist the load (even if executed inside a loop), simply because the load is hidden inside the de-reference of a virtual function call.

The runnable instance is decoupled from the executor, so that it will not be devirtualized/inlined when the MyExecutor class is compiled.

The read is then performed by 2 levels of indirection and the load will not be hoisted when main performs the 2 sequential prints.

---

Using getOpaque to prevent this... in this case will only incur in the overhead of the introspection + cast (I mean even volatile is preferred instead of `getOpaque` tbh).

And, because memory hoisting is a pure compiler behavior, the argument of "Ok, it works now, but... what about weakly memory ordered processors?" has no impact, since the compilers will remain the same even if the processor changes...

So, I think, the real question would be, What makes `memory_order_relaxed`/`read_once`/`getOpaque` so special in the eyes of the processor?

Alternately If getOpaque's usage is widely done to prevent simplification/hoisting (during for loop inlining) or in recurrent loads, then the behavior makes sense to be implemented more as a pair of reordering atomic fences within the jump loop, than as a "targeted" load/store reordering rule made on a specific register,... unless this is what is actually happening under the hood with relaxed...:

```
//pardon my pseudo code


   T local;

   // ^^^^...Keep reordering above this point...^^^

   atomic_fence(); //Nothing above can go bellow and viceversa.
   local = fieldVal;
   atomic_fence(); //Nothing bellow can go above and viceversa.

   // vvv...Keep reordering bellow this point...vvv

   return local;
```

So what I believe is that the hoisting behavior is NOT related to the reordering one.
So memory_order_relaxed and homologous instructions are doing 2 jobs.

- ONE) to communicate the compiler to prevent compiler hoisting + reordering.
- SECOND) to prevent reordering (hence simplification) during processor reordering.

Will my code work to perform double-checking? absolutely NOT.

Will it work as a concurrent proactive load of a given register... absolutely... but... what about weakly memory ordered processors?

Comment: *a) The level of processor reordering is limited by the amount of method de-virtualization done by the compiler.* - Huh?  Branch prediction + speculative execution lets out-of-order exec see past indirect calls.  Also, memory reordering is separate from out-of-order exec.  e.g. the store buffer creates StoreLoad reordering on its own, and ISAs with weakly ordered memory models allow out-of-order commit from the store buffer if a uarch wants to do that.  Separate from the order of execution (writing store address+data into the store buffer.)

Comment: Speculation is still bounded by the virtual function call, why would speculation de-virtualize methods while the "front" (non-speculative) code sequence is still virtual?

Speculation does not reorder, the reordering will happen before any speculation takes place, speculation loads can happen cross core cache (for verification) OR to main register (for verification).

Again by this time, any reordering/hoisting already happened.... WAY BEFORE the speculation took place....

Comment: *Speculation is still bounded by the virtual function call,* No, run-time speculative execution by the CPU itself is *not* bounded by indirect calls.  This can create run-time memory reordering across those boundaries, regardless of compile-time ordering.

Comment: Ok, I'll trust you... it is not bound... it would still fail verification. and the write will not perform, the speculation would/should be discarded.

Comment: Only on *mis*-speculation.  If the speculation is confirmed (correct branch prediction), then no rollback has to happen.  The out-of-order exec results can be committed (retired).  This is the same reason that C++ `std::memory_order_consume` only deals with data dependencies, not control dependencies.  The reason speculation inside CPUs is useful in the first place is that it can become non-speculative once the thing is confirmed.

Comment: I've only seen false positives on confirmations... on concurrency with acyclic interdependence. which is the cases researches use for speculation to fail with plain loads.
Aside from these, all errors come from the ones discussed in my question which are compiler related.

Comment: Having said this, I definitely see the validity of your argument, whatever may go wrong... will go wrong.

Comment: *What makes memory_order_relaxed/read_once/getOpaque so special in the eyes of the processor?* - nothing, except that the load actually happens in the asm, not optimized into a register.  (And is done with a single instruction to avoid tearing; in C or C++, see [Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71866535) - some optimization can turn an assignment to a register-width variable into something that isn't on-paper guaranteed to be atomic.  (AArch64 GCC using `stp` with a pair

Comment: I was under the impression that the "=" syntax would never allow tearing, meaning the MESI propagation would never deliver the reference of a partially built object.
As someone also told me once, object oriented compilers enforce memory barriers by fencing the last line of the constructor (on `volatile` objects exclusively) AND by means of virtual function "compactness" (nothing can go outside the virtual function of the constructor call). Of course this would not apply under the case of speculations tearing all virtual functions as you just mentioned.
But it still seems to me the tearing...

Comment: ...responsibility relies in the writing/storing side, in the case of the question I am discussing the loading side... and the loading side is not really responsible for a partially visible object (even assuming complete object tearing).

Comment: Java is a different language from C++.  In C and C++, it's fully undefined behaviour to have unsynchronized access to non-`atomic` variables, so compilers can make asm that could potentially tear, in the rare cases where that's faster.  I think Java probably forbids that, at least for values up to 32-bit?  I don't think Java could in general promise 64-bit `long` atomicity since that would be expensive on 32-bit systems (prohibitively expensive on some 32-bit systems where it would require locking).

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, on 32 bit JVM, 64 bit non volatile long/double can run into tearing. But a volatile long/double can't.

Comment: @Delark opaque needs to provide atomicity and coherence. All modern processors are coherent, so no memory fences are needed for that. But compiler optimizations can cause incoherence, so they need to be kept under control.

Comment: Thanks @pveentjer, (Ignoring the hoisting mechanic since that seems 100% a responsibility of the compiler) It seems the virtual machine handles sequences by segments (method handle lookup and call). So each segment (stack-frame) maintains some degree of the PO.

Actions such as "double check" DO happen most often than not within the same stack-frame and so in this case opaque would prevent a reordering + simplification at compilation within these frames.

But in cases in which opaque checks happen cross stack-frames opaqueness would be irrelevant... UNLESS... the processor is capable of...

Comment: inlining ALL stack-frames and execute EVERYTHING in a big lengthy sequence (Where ALL that exists are loads, stores and logic)... in this scenario, if the processor chooses to reorder a second time... then an issue may arise if no memory barriers were enforced... ALSO in this scenario, the processor wouldn't need to interact with the virtual machine or hypervisor... Is this a real processor behavior?