# std::atomic<int> vs. an aligned-to-native-word int varible, which is better?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, atomic, lock-free

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

alignas(sizeof(void*)) int n1;
std::atomic<int> n2;

int main() {
    std::thread threads[32];

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread = std::thread([] {
            while (true) {
                // randomly load and/or store n1, n2
            }
        });
    }
    
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Consider the code above:

- `n1` is aligned to the native word boundary, so it can be loaded and stored atomically without a LOCK prefix at the assembly instruction level.
- `n2` is a `std::atomic`, I'm not sure whether it will use a LOCK prefix at the assembly instruction level.

My question is:

**Is it always safe to use an aligned-to-native-word** `int` **varible , instead of an** `std::atomic<int>` **variable, for the best performance gain?**

Comment: What matters is whether the compiler "knows" that `int` is atomic, not whether you know that it can be read and written atomically

Comment: In other words, if I need a global `int` variable for multi-threading access, can I always safely use an aigned-to-native-word `int` variable, rather than an `std::atomic<int>` variable?

Comment: *"Is it always safe"* No! It is not safe. You must not use `n1` in a parallel code (without additional synchronizations). This is Undefined Behaviour. Correctness matters more than performance. A compiler is free to assume `n1` is not modified by another thread and mainstream optimizing compiler already do such an optimization.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, what if `alignas(sizeof(void*)) int volatile n1`?

Comment: What is the reason you want to avoid `std::atomic<int>` ? Such a use case is exactly its pupose. If you are bothered about locking overhead, you can check `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free` and `std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free` on you system.

Comment: BTW if you use an `std::atomic<int>` with at most acquire-load and release-store (not sequential consistency) (the load/store doesn't need to be relaxed, that's more freedom than necessary, but you can use that too) then on x86 you don't pay any additional fences or other nonsense. It's *as if* you were using a non-atomic `int` but it actually works the way you want it to.

Comment: ... and if this would be ok, why expect `std::atomic<int>` would do something worse?

Comment: @wohlstad, If it can be done without any other dependency, I think it may be better.

Comment: Besides, AFAIK, read and store to `n2` should be equally fast on modern mainstream x86-64 architectures if you use *relaxed* loads/stores (otherwise, for sequentially consistent operations, there a LOCK prefix should be certainly generated). The benefit of atomics, besides correctness, is that you can also perform RMW operations on them easily and control memory barriers. Note you can align `std::atomic` variables too (they are AFAIK not guaranteed to be aligned nor often actually aligned).

Comment: @xmllmx `std::atomic` is a part of the standard library so I don't see what dependency you mean. Also I didn't understand in what sense it would be better. Usually you can count on the standard library to supply an optimal implementation for such cases. Do you have a different experience on your system ?

Comment: @JérômeRichard atomic variables are already aligned (to their natural alignment) of course, and all non-atomic variables too. OP is over-aligning it which isn't necessary.

Comment: `volatile` is another concept. It does not ensure atomicity (alone). You can do atomic operation on volatile variables so for it to behave like `std::atomic` (like in old C programs) and it will certainly fix the UB issue, but IMHO this is a convoluted non-standard way to operate on atomic variables. Like others here, I do not understand the purpose of doing this.

Comment: @harold I mean not aligned to a cache line (which matters for false sharing, but it is certainly not needed here). Sorry, I should have clarified that. I agree with you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866535/which-types-on-a-64-bit-computer-are-naturally-atomic-in-gnu-c-and-gnu-c-m).  This shows examples where data race UB on aligned machine-word-size variables behaves in undesired ways.

Comment: It's true that, on most platform, normal load and store instructions of aligned native words are atomic.  But the flaw in your reasoning is that the C++ compiler is not obliged to translate a read or write of a native-word-size variable into a single machine load or store instruction.  It may emit something else which is not atomic.

Comment: This misconception seems to be very widespread; I've seen it in several questions on this site.  I wonder if there is some popular book or website that contains erroneous information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Is it always safe to use an aligned-to-native-word int varible , instead of an std::atomic variable, for the best performance gain?"

1. **It's definately not safe:**
   According to the [C++ memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) accessing `n1` from multiple threads in this case constitutes a **data race**. And as you can see in the link above:

   > If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined.

   Having an [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means anything can happen, and you should always avoid it.
   One possible result could be that compiler will optimize away reads of `n1` assuming it is not modified by another thread.
   (Note that the atomicity of read/write de-facto due to alignment to word boundary etc. does not preclude a data race).
2. **Regarding performance:**
   [`std::atomic<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) is a part of the standard library. It is meant for such cases exactly.
   The standard library usually supplies the most optimal implementation for these primitives, and you need a really special reason (which you did not specify) to avoid using it.
   If you are concerned about the overhead of locking, you can check [`std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free), and [`std::atomic<T>::is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) (from C++17).
   But keep in mind that if is is not lock free, it means that a lock is really required.

---

Additional info regarding performance (courtacy of Peter Cordes):

`std::atomic<int>` is lock-free on all modern mainstream systems (except 8-bit microcontrollers) so you don't really have to worry about that.

The default `memory_order` for operations on `std::atomic` is `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.  On x86, that costs extra for `.store`, but not for loads or RMWs.  Use `.load(acquire)` and `.store(val, release)` so the compiler doesn't have to use any extra barrier instructions (or `xchg` for a seq-cst store), unless something you're doing actually needs some of the guarantees that sequential consistency gives but acq/rel don't.  (The expensive part being StoreLoad ordering, and no [IRIW reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see) even on PowerPC where that costs extra barriers to prevent.)

Comment: For performance, you should be using `.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` and `.store(value, std::memory_order_release)`.  That makes it basically free on x86, and as efficient as possible on AArch64 and most other modern ISAs.  `seq_cst` stores do cost a lot extra on x86 especially, being a full barrier so it hurts memory-level parallelism for surrounding code, too.  (`relaxed` is even cheaper on some ISAs, and if you only have one shared variable that's all you need.)  TL:DR: lock-free or not isn't the only condition for atomic being cheap.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the additional info. Feel free to edit my answer if you think it should be added there. In any case my main point is that the OP should use `std::atomic` rather than the suggested `alignof` "trick".