Whether read/write for an cacheline-unaligned 8-byte variable is atomic or not on x86_64?
I am confused about when to use atomic_t in C.
Some people say there's no need to use atomic_t to protect simple read and write operations on a variable smaller than 8 bytes on x86_64 (such as long or int).
Others say that only cache-aligned variables can guarantee atomicity.
To clarify, I wrote a simple program to test this. In the program, I start 128 threads to operate on a global, cache-unaligned long variable. The even-numbered threads set the variable to 1, while the odd-numbered threads set it to -1. Afterward, they assert that the variable is either -1 or 1.
When I run this program multiple times, the assertion fails occasionally.
The code is below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 128

struct foo{
    char pad[54];
    long val;
    char pad2[54];
};


struct foo global __attribute__((aligned(64)));

void* thread_func(void* arg) {
    int thread_id = *((int*)arg);

    for (int j=0;j<100000;j++) {
    if (thread_id % 2 == 0)
            global.val = 1;
        else
            global.val = -1;
    }

    assert(global.val == -1 || global.val == 1);

    return NULL;
}

int is_aligned_to_64(void *ptr) {
    return ((uintptr_t)ptr % 64) == 0;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    printf("Initial value of global: %p\n", &(global.val));
    global.val=0;

    assert(!is_aligned_to_64(&(global.val)));

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        int* thread_id = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *thread_id = i;
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_func, (void*)thread_id) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create thread");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("Final value of global: %ld\n", global.val);

    return 0;
}

The output of the program in my server is like
# ./atomic
Initial value of global: 0x6010f8
Final value of global: 1
# ./atomic
Initial value of global: 0x6010f8
Final value of global: 1
# ./atomic
Initial value of global: 0x6010f8
Final value of global: -1
# ./atomic
Initial value of global: 0x6010f8
Final value of global: -1
# ./atomic
Initial value of global: 0x6010f8
atomic: atomic.c:29: thread_func: Assertion `global.val == -1 || global.val == 1' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)


Please don't tag the C program with C++.

What makes you think the access is unaligned?

"Some people say there's no need to use atomic_t to protect simple read and write operations on a variable smaller than 8 bytes on x86_64"  Some people are fools. The C language simply do not guarantee atomicity of any read or write no matter the variable size unless you use atomic qualifiers.

@AhmedAEK  My guess is like : one thread writes 0xff0 to a shared variable, and another thread writes 0x0ff. Since the writes are not atomic, the value of the shared variable could end up being 0xfff.

@PepijnKramer I make an assertion before creating thread.
assert(!is_aligned_to_64(&(global.val)));

This checks for 64-byte alignment. 8-byte values don't need to be 64-byte aligned. Also, did you compile with optimizations enabled? Without optimizations, the compiler will read the value twice from memory, once for each of the conditions.

@Lundin  So, what mention in this link is wrong? https://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/so-what-is-a-memory-model-and-how-to-cook-it
"Regarding loads and stores. Memory model along with instruction set specifies whether plain loads and stores are atomic or not. Typical guarantee for all modern commodity hardware is that aligned word-sized loads and stores are atomic. For example, on x86 architecture (IA-32 and Intel 64) 1-, 2-, 4-, 8- and 16-byte aligned loads and stores are all atomic (that is, plain MOV instruction, MOVQ and MOVDQA are atomic)."

@plznobug i think tkausl comment is the reason why the assert fires, the variables is read twice, AFAIK x86_64 can do 8 or even 16 byte reads or writes, the variable cannot be in a mixed state, this doesn't mean the code above doesn't have a data race.

@AhmedAEK hmm.. I still didn't get it. Even the variable is read twice, the value should be still either -1 or 1.

@plznobug That link isn't even about C programming. The problem seems to be that you think C instructions directly translate into something like a single RMW instruction, but there are no guarantees that the compiler will do that. Unless perhaps you declared the variable as atomic.

@AhmedAEK Oh, I see. The first read is 1 which breaks the left part of the assert and the second read is -1 which breaks the right part.

@plznobug there are many reasons to use atomics, for example you need to establish a release sequence for other data in caches, also the compiler cannot optimize away or merge atomic writes, but it can do that with non-atomic writes, also reordering of instructions comes to play. also RMW operations are different and need to be done atomically, atomic reads are zero cost though, they use the same instruction as a normal load.

@AhmedAEK so, no matter what, x86_64 can do 8bytes read or write in an atomic manner, concurrent write would not make it in a mixed state?

@plznobug yes, but you still have a data race, you don't have any guarantee on the order of operations and whether or not they will happen to begin with, imagine a progress bar that you update every iteration, the compiler is free to combine all increments into a single one that it does at the beginning or end of the loop if the operation is not atomic, and volatile is a worse deal because it still doesn't guarantee the relative order of operations

since we are on the topic, i will drop this video here on why atomics matter Herb Sutter - atomic Weapons

@AhmedAEK Actually volatile does guarantee sequencing of everything before/after it. But it doesn't guarantee atomic access.

atomicity != cache coherency It is not the same.

I started to write an answer, but a lot of it overlapped with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866535/which-types-on-a-64-bit-computer-are-naturally-atomic-in-gnu-c-and-gnu-c-m/71867102#71867102, so I'd like to suggest you read that first.

Indeed, I think the basic source of confusion is that you are reading the memory model rules of the x86_64 architecture (i.e. how individual assembly instructions behave), and assuming that they apply to C programs being compiled and run on x86_64.  This is false.  Even when you have an operation in C (e.g. assigning to a long variable) and an operation in assembly language (mov [mem], rax) that are very similar, you can't assume the rules of the latter apply to the former, because the compiler is allowed to implement assignment to a long with something other than a single mov.

So this is the first issue.  Decide whether you are asking a question about C, or about x86_64 assembly.  If the former, your only guiding source is the ISO C standard; put the Intel/AMD manuals back on the shelf as they are irrelevant to you.  If the latter, then don't use a C program as your test case.  Either way, be wary of third-party sources, since it seems you've been reading ones that contain wrong information, or else you've misunderstood it.

This answer summarize the comments, clarify what happens when you run your code and point out what the C11 standard states about that.


Some people say there's no need to use atomic_t to protect simple read and write operations on a variable smaller than 8 bytes on x86_64 (such as long or int).

This is wrong (for basic non-atomic non-volatile variables). The compiler can assume that a variable is not modified by other threads when there is no synchronization (e.g. locks, memory barrier, atomic operations) between them. The compiler can change the order of the operation, can remove code with data race or even remove assert only possibly true when a data race happen. Spoil: compilers actually do that!

When I run this program multiple times, the assertion fails occasionally.

If you compile the code without optimizations, the compiler should (not guaranteed) read global.val from memory, compare it to -1, then read it again and compare it to 1. The the value is read twice from memory as pointed out by @tkausl. The thing is the value can change between the two read, switching from 1 to -1 so the two comparison results in false and so the assert is raised.
If you enable optimization, the compiler can assume no other threads modify the value (or read the modified value without synchronization) because it is undefined behaviour (UB) (and compilers can assume there is no UB in your code) due to a data race. This enable more aggressive optimizations in many case. For example, here, in -O2, both GCC and Clang optimize out the loop because they see that there is no point writing 100000 times the same value in a loop. This is also true in -O1 with Clang (GCC do not completely optimize out the loop but the effect is the same). Then both compiler see that the assert is useless so they remove it (remember there the data race possibly happening between the two reads is UB so this optimization is completely legit).
Here is the generated code with GCC (see on Godbolt):
thread_func:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        not     eax
        and     eax, 1
        cmp     al, 1
        sbb     rax, rax
        or      rax, 1
        mov     QWORD PTR global[rip+56], rax
        xor     eax, eax
        ret

As we can see: there is no loop anymore nor any assertion! GCC only writes in global.val.

What about (aligned) volatile?
Ok, but what about using aligned volatile accesses so to force compilers to always read and write the long-typed variable from memory?
Technically, in C11, this is still UB because of the data race since volatile accesses are not guaranteed to be atomic in C11 (be careful of interrupts) independently of the target platform. And even if so, I think it would be still be UB because "neither happens before the other" (due to no synchronization) but let's put this aside for the moment. Here is what the C11 standard draft explicitly states:

Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.


The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

That being said, the compiler cannot optimize read and write because volatile accesses they are side effect. They cannot make any assumption on the content of the variable in memory either since it can change (stopping the program, modifying the value and continuing it is completely legit). They cannot and even must not do any assumptions on the state of such variables before doing the actual access (beside other constraints like ones based on their type). Here is what the C11 standard states:

Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects.


An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects. Therefore any expression referring to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, as described in 5.1.2.3. Furthermore, at every sequence point the value last stored in the object shall agree with that prescribed by the abstract machine, except as modified by the unknown factors mentioned previously. What constitutes an access to an object that
has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.

Compiler cannot reorder or optimizing-out the accesses as they want as explicitly stated in the C11 standard draft:

Actions on objects so declared shall not be ‘‘optimized out’’ by an implementation or reordered except as permitted by the rules for evaluating expressions.

Moreover, you should not mix volatile and non-volatile accesses on the same variable:

If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behaviour is undefined.

On top of that, if you know that the volatile accesses are always atomic on the target platform, then, in practice, it would be Ok, though it will only work on the target platform. The thing is you must be sure that all possible instructions generated by the compiler from volatile variables are atomic ones on the target platform (including cases involving interruptions), as pointed out by @Lundin. Moreover, there is a slight ambiguity about whether volatile accesses can be considered atomic even in this case because they are not explicitly defined as atomic in the abstract machine even though they would actually be truly atomic at the hardware level.
One might argues that this theoretical ambiguity is certainly not a real-world problem because compilers cannot optimize volatile accesses due to side-effects anyway. However, there are tricky cases were this can be an issue. For example, if you write a = (b = c) where a, b and c are all volatile variables, then the compiler is free to reload b from memory or not resulting in a possibly non-atomic operation overall depending on the compiler implementation (and not just the target CPU architecture). See the standard:

The implementation is permitted to read the object to determine the value but is not required to, even when the object has volatile-qualified type.

Moreover, if you write operation like a += 1, be aware that this operation will typically results in separate read+write since there is no reason for a compiler to generate an atomic operation (which are significantly slower), and be aware that classical RMW instructions are not atomic in x86-64 unless there is a LOCK prefix.
As for whether writes are truly atomics in this case, see Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes pointed out by @NateEldredge.
Honestly, don't use (only) volatile for atomic accesses. This is like playing with radioactive waste, or atomic weapons depending on the point of view (thanks to @AhmedAEK for the link). I might work in practice but spuriously fail one day and cause very sneaky issues (e.g. what about non-standard x86-64 CPUs, future ones, special kind of memory areas, x86-64 emulation on ARM CPUs, etc.). I see no reason not to use atomics. They are designed for this specific purpose. If you really care about performance, then try to reduce the number of atomic operations and give hints to the compiler so it can generate faster code, check the resulting generated instruction and profile your code to be sure this is actually the main bottleneck. Indeed, while atomic writes can often be translated to basic writes on x86-64 CPUs because basic writes (to classical memory area) are implicitly followed by an release memory barrier on such platform. I wonder if this is true on write-combining memory pages (AFAIK this is not the case so you might see observable effects).

Instead of the assert() outputting the value of global.val twice might be revealing. But as pointed out because there is no (memory barrier) synchronisation applied to that variable the compiler may elide one or both of the reads. A common flaw is people reason about concurrent writes but still reason believing there is a single main memory in an optimiser free Von Neumann Architecture (VNA). As soon as you introduce threads VNA is inadequate on modern platforms (mutli-core multi-level cache).
